# Hide Main report also, when sub report does not contain data - SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have one main report which shows the order details and one subreport which shows order items details. Here I passed orderno as parameter to subreport. It has multiple records group by order number. so for each order number, there are seperate set of records. I want to hide both sub report and main report when sum of demand value in subreport is zero or blank, sum of supply > sum of demand. Now I can able to hide only sub report by using the following Condition :

```
=IIF(Sum(IsNothing(Fields!Demand.Value)) OR Sum(Fields!Demand.Value = "") OR
(Sum(Fields!Supply.Value) > Sum(Fields!Demand.Value)), False, True)
```

But here, the main report data is showing which I want to hide. How can we hide both main and subreport based on value in subreport?
Can anyone help me to do this?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: create same dataset like subreport on main report. and use the same expression to set visibility. it should work

Answer (score 0):

You can return some flag in your main report data for example "DoShow" and then set visibility based on that flag to hide rows in main report.

Answer (score 0):

*Copy Sub Report DataSet to Main Report Datasets and Use same expression for visibility.*

**OR**

Create another procedure to set visibility.

**For example:** We can create one stored procedure to hide both "Sub report and Main report" - when sum of demand value in subreport is zero or blank, sum of supply > sum of demand.

*Let me know, if you need more help.*

Comment: I copy subreport dataset to main report. But here actually pass orderno. from main report to subreport dynamically. So for this newly created subreport dataset i am not able to pass parameter

Comment: Is there any posiibility using rownumber of tablix? To hide/show one row  based on next row

Comment: Sorry but want to know, have you done something for this query?

Comment: Can you please check it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591039/look-up-function-inside-if-condition-visibility-ssrs

Answer (score 0):

> Use the same condition you have used to hide sub report in main report
>   as well.

I am assuming you are using a separate tablix for main and sub reports. If so, right click on main report tablix -->tablix properties --> Click on Visibility --> Now click on "Show or Hide based on expression" and paste the IIF condition which worked for subreport over here. This should definitely work. Give it a shot and let me know how it goes. Mark answered if it works please.

Cheers and all the best

Comment: I am using the subreport inside the row of main report's tablix

Comment: I am hiding the row(contains subeport) by : IIF(RowNumber(Nothing)>0,False,True) and if i use subreport dataset in main report , there actually pass orderno. from main report to subreport dynamically. So for this newly created subreport dataset i am not able to pass parameter

Comment: @KaviSuja I understand you have used row visibility property to hide/show based on your expression for Sub report. If its a single tablix, then I truly believe using the same condition (which you have used for subreport to hide) against the row which contains main tablix should be suffice.
#Option 2 - You can try separating out Main and Sub report in two different tablix and proceed as per my orginal suggestion. 
Let me know how it goes.