# Look up function inside IF condition visibility - SSRS

Tags: if-statement, reporting-services, lookup, ssrs-tablix

I  have a SSRS report with one tablix and i want to hide the tablix based on a condition. I am using two datasets there. The tablix contains dataset1 records. I want to check the dataset2 with Pno and if then only need to display that Pno in tablix.

```
Dataset1                        
Pno Group
 1  A
2   S
3   D
4   F
Dataset2
Pno Supply  Demand  Group
1           A
3           D
5           B
6           R
Now I want to display only 
Pno Group
1   A
3   D
```

I am using the following condition.

```
=IIF(Lookup(Fields!Group.Value, Fields!Pno.Value, Fields!Pno.value, "Dataset2"), True, False)
```

But it doesn't filter the records. Can anyone help me to solve this?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may just have your Lookup parameters mixed up. Try this:

```
=IIF(Lookup(Fields!Pno.Value, Fields!Pno.value, Fields!Group.Value, "Dataset2"), True, False)
```

One step further:

```
=IIF(Lookup(Fields!Pno.Value, Fields!Pno.value, Fields!Group.Value, "Dataset2") <> "", True, False)
```

In a Lookup, the first 2 parameters are the fields that need to match, the third is the value being returned, the fourth is the dataset being queried.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this expression in for hidden in the Row visibility window:

[image]

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(ReportItems!Group.Value),True,False)
```

ReportTems!Group is the name of the cell where you are using the Lookup function, replace Group by the actual name of the cell:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Group.Value, Fields!Pno.Value, Fields!Pno.value, "Dataset2")
```

If your cell has a different name select the cell and press F4 to see the properties window, look for the name property.

It will produce:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.